# Why do I have to reinstall Kinect SDK everytime I restart PC

Tags: sdk, kinect

I'm currently work with `Kinect for Windows SDK version 1` under Win7, VS2010, C#.NET.

Demos in `Microsoft Kinect for Windows SDK Sample Browser` can't run properly after Kinect is connected to my PC.

- *Kinect Explorer*(in **C#**) says **Kinect is not ready** (which is different from **Please insert a Kinect...** if Kinect is not connected).
- *Shapes Game*(in **C#**) says **Oops... Something's wrong with Kinect**
- *Skeletal Viewer*(in **C++**) can run, but only depth image run properly. Color image has a frame rate less than 1! And skeleton view show nothing but a black background.

Here's what I have tried:

- The above thing will not happen(which means everything goes all right) if SDK is reinstalled and PC is not restarted. So... I have to **reinstall Kinect SDK everytime I restart my PC!!!**
- I checked the *Resource Manager* after Kinect USB is plugged to my PC. The strange thing is that if the PC is not restarted after reinstalling SDK, there're 4 devices concerning Kinect: Audio, Speech, NUI and Security. But after restart PC, **the Security Device won't be shown** after Kinect is connected to PC.
- I've tried with 2 different Kinect(one at a time) and have the same situation.
- Using different USB slots make no difference.

I don't know what's wrong with my PC or how to do next. The only thing I know is that I don't want to reinstall Kinect SDK everytime I restart my PC! So would anybody offer some solution? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this problem just now, and finally solve it. I accidentally killed the process names "KinectManagementService" in the task manager, and then I could not connect the Kinect any more. Have a glance at the task manager whether the process is there.

Open Windows Service, and start the service "Kinect Management". That's it!

Comment: I've done with the Kinect and I don't have one at hand. Will it work if you restart your PC? Because I guess it will work if it is the problem of service.