# "No ready Kinect found!" message

Tags: c#, kinect

I've just installed Kinect Studio and Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit.
I have followed the instructions on this [site.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/readme.htm)

However, when I open one of the developer toolkits, I get the error:

> No ready kinect found.

I've tried all the options given in other discussions about problems with the given error:

1. [Why do I have to reinstall Kinect SDK everytime I restart PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406777/why-do-i-have-to-reinstall-kinect-sdk-everytime-i-restart-pc),
2. [Kinect gives a "NotReady" status in .Net samples works in C++ samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982005/kinect-gives-a-notready-status-in-net-samples-works-in-c-samples/9983546#9983546),
3. [No ready kinect found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841069/no-ready-kinect-found)

None of these answers solved my problem.

The kinetic is working on the PC of one of my colleagues, so I guess it is due to some settings on my laptop.

Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: I think you'll be pretty lucky to find someone who knows the answer to what is likely an obscure hardware or software setup issue on a site about programming issues... you may be better off looking for answers on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home).

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll check that site.